# How does difficulty is defined for block '55798'?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

I know that the formula for calculating the difficulty is below -

```
Difficulty = T (max) / T
Where T (max) = 1d00ffff in decimal it is 486604799.
```

[image: **enter image description here**]

As you can see in the above screenshot the difficulty of block '55798' is **12.85**. I'm trying to calculate this value using formula but getting the different result.

```
D = T (max) / T
```

When I put the correct values in the formula, It becomes like -

```
D = (486604799 / 471067731) = 1.03
```

I don't know why I'm getting the different difficulty. The correct value is 12.85. Can you please let me know the reason of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to calculate difficulty from Bits fields (which is stored in block).

1. Convert value to hex: `bits=471067731 -> 0x1c13ec53`
2. Split hex value, take 8 high bits (`0x1c`), and 24 low (`0x13ec53`)
3. Use [formula](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_is_difficulty_stored_in_blocks.3F) to get 256-bit target value: `T = low * 2 ^ (8 * (high - 3))`. In our case it will be: `T = 0x13ec53 * 2 ^ (8 * (0x1c - 3)) = 0x0000000013ec5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
4. Divide highest possible target Tmax (`0x00000000ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`) by our T. If we truncate zeros, it will be: `0x13ec53 / 0xffff00 = 12.849`

---

Network recalculates difficulty every 2016 blocks (2 weeks). This is how 12.85 is getting recalculated from block timestamps:

```
block -  diff - time stamp
...
52415 -  7.82 (2010-04-21 21:50:53)
52416 - 11.46 (2010-04-21 21:52:52) <- difficulty update
...
54430 - 11.46 (2010-05-04 09:39:19)
54431 - 11.46 (2010-05-04 09:40:03)
54432 - 12.85 (2010-05-04 09:46:16) <- difficulty update
...
55798 - 12.85 (2010-05-14 16:21:05) <- your block
```

When network recalculates difficulty, it takes time to mine the latest 2015 blocks (due to bug in code, it should take 2016). In our example, it would be:

```
2010-05-04 09:40:03 - 2010-04-21 21:52:52 = 12.491 days
```

In normal scenario 2016 block should be mined in 14 days. So, new difficulty:

```
11.46 * 14 / 12.491 = 12.844
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But why we added 11.46 in our calculation? any reason for this? and why you added 12.491? what about the formula D = T(max) / T

Comment: 11.46 is previous difficulty. To calculate new difficulty network takes previous one. You can't use Bits field directly and do division. It has internal format, You can read wiki for details: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty "How is difficulty stored in blocks?"

Comment: Please let me know what formula you have used to calculate the difficulty.

Comment: `new_diff = old_diff * ratio`

Comment: I think the question is about how difficulty is calculated from bits, not about how the difficulty is actually determined from previous block timestamps.

Comment: @Shubham oh, sorry, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Zergatul Thanks you so much for your great help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Zergatul Can you please let me know how to convert the '0x0000000013ec5300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' floating point number into decimal. ? Any online conversion link would really help me.

Comment: @Shubham I prefer to use programming languages, for example in javascript: `0x13ec53 * Math.pow(2, 8 * (0x1c - 3))`. And result: `2.0981516864422112e+66`