# Why is the target truncated?

Tags: bitcoin-core, hash, difficulty, storage

Reading the docs on [target](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Target):

> The maximum target used by SHA256 mining devices is:
>
> 0x00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
>
> Because Bitcoin stores the target as a **floating-point type**, this is truncated:
>
> 0x00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I know that the purpose is to force miners to generate hashes with a value lower than the target. But the docs are vague, why is this truncation required? And then, why truncate after the first four Fs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target is stored in block header (it's called Bits), and it takes only 4 bytes. We derive target 256-bit value from these 32 bits. That's why it is getting truncated.

There is no need to store all 256 bits, or even 224 bits (if we assume first 4 bytes are zero). We don't need such precision.

You can [read in wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_is_difficulty_stored_in_blocks.3F), how target is getting calculated from Bits.

You can also check my answer here, with example: 
[How does difficulty is defined for block '55798'?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/75625/how-does-difficulty-is-defined-for-block-55798/75627#75627)

Comment: This was really clear, thanks! Just to make sure, setting the trailing bites of the 256-bit version to zero means that when a miner finds a hash with a value which has the correct number of zeros, but it is higher than the target, that hash is invalid?

Comment: @PaulRBerg right, we talk about trailing zeros for simple explanation. In the reality we compare two 256-bit integers